# Stack Overflow header redesign hurts community reviews

Tags: discussion, review-stats, header

I've noticed that after the header redesign

[image: Stack Overflow menu bar with reviews icon indicated]

The number of community-pending reviews has gone through the roof.

Personally I dislike the redesign, and I think it's horrible. I'm an old time user and the older header was much better and it was much more appealing to help the community there. (Help with closed votes especially.)

I constantly saw the number of pending reviews and it "hurt" me when that number was too high (for me it was above `1,000`) and now it's over `9,000` since the redesign!

I think the psychological effect of the old header was obviously noticeable and it saddens me there were no A/B tests which would have predicted this by measuring how many people clicked the "review" button.

#### old header:[image: old header]

It's clearly as psychological design error.

Comment: I think it belongs to MSO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the top bar redesign the sole cause of the suggested edit slowdown?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349118) See also [Has the top bar redesign met its goals?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349204)

Comment: @SagarV since this new header is about to arrive all sites soon, I'm not sure.

Comment: The only reason you saw just 1000 is because on SO the count for the close vote queue was always left out. Previously that number was a lie, now you have the actual data, which is better IMO, don't hide the numbers we don't like.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - thanks! I knew somebody else had figured this out but couldn't find where a discussion like this was. Thanks again! this is super important stuff.

Comment: Well, if everyone with close vote privileges would strive to be on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) on a daily basis, I call it problem solved. Gather your friends, colleagues  and family and  use your close votes ...

Comment: @rene - it should be mandatory to help in reviews or else one will loose points

Comment: Here's [my own naive theory on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349946).

Comment: @JasonC - you are right. I think it's a huge shock that a website with such **massive** wisdom of off a mass of people behind it had done such a horrible redesign of huge basic psychological mistakes. such things should not happen here. I would personally fire the person who promoted such a move.

Comment: @vsync I believe the removal of persistent highlighting was part of [this change that removed the count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346653/616460), which I believe was done primarily for performance reasons. Also please do not fire anybody. Seems a bit harsh. :P The new top bar is still a work in progress.

Comment: @JasonC - simply A/B testing... just sayin'.